# AS3 AIR : Android Application : ApplicationDirectory vs applicationStorageDirectory

Tags: android, actionscript-3, sqlite, air, flash-builder

I am developping an application for Android using flash builder and AIR.

This application is already available on the Google Play Store. I use a SQLite databse to keep the access to levels for users.

I've to do an update because there are some bugs. I'm afraid of losing all user data with the update.

At the moment, this is the way I'm stocking to my database :

```
var embededSessionDB:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("./db/mamygaga.sqlite");
```

Questions are :

- My database in ApplicationDirectory is going to be deleted ?
- applicationStorageDirectory is better ?

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: never use applicationDirectory for file you need to write to or read from, that's the rule. You didn't want to follow the rule and you'll lose all your data of course. You can only blame it on you.

Comment: Thank you for reply BotMaster... I had to use applicationStorageDirectory ?

Comment: yes this is the safest directory, it won't be overwritten, you'll be able to write and read from it.

Comment: `applicationStorageDirectory` is the best/most appropriate place to store persistent user data on the device.  Though cloud storage is even better.

Comment: Might be worth testing this:  try leaving your sqlite database out of your update package.  Add some code to create the sqlite database if it doesn't exist on app startup.  I'm not sure if updating an android app clears the application directory or not (I would guess not), so if there is no file to overwrite the old one, it may work. (Just a guess though, I've never looked into this before)

Comment: If you do test my suggestion, please let everyone know your results

Comment: Sorry but i just change ma code to copy my databse in applicationStorageDirectory. I didn't test your solution.